# Database connect scope when using grep

Tags: bash, sed, grep, db2, db2-luw

Trying to get 2 character version from database table sysibm.sysversions. This is working independently with:

```
db2 -x "select versionnumber from sysibm.sysversions where UPPER(authid) = UPPER('db2dev')" | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//' | head -c2
```

This gives the result:

> 11

Trying to incorporate this into a script is giving strange results

```
db2 connect to sample

_dbversion=$(db2 -x "select versionnumber from sysibm.sysversions where UPPER(authid) = UPPER('${_dbuser}')"  | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//')
echo -e "${_dbversion}"
```

This gives connection errors

> SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003

I can get around this by either performing the grep outside of select

db2 connect to sample

```
_dbversion=$(db2 -x "select versionnumber from sysibm.sysversions where UPPER(authid) = UPPER('${_dbuser}')")
_dbversion_head=$(echo -e ${_dbversion1} | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//' | head -c2)
echo -e "${_dbversion_head}"
```

Or connecting within the brackets

```
_dbversion=$(db2 -x connect to sample; db2 -x "select versionnumber from sysibm.sysversions where UPPER(authid) = UPPER('${_dbuser}')" | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//' | head -c2)
```

Is it possible to have the connect scope be extended when using grep/sed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe causes `db2 -x "select..."` to execute in a subshell, while the connection remains local to the parent shell.

You can simply put both `connect` and `select` into a file (or even here-document) to run them as a script and thus guarantee that both execute in the same session:

```
db2 -x <<EOF | sed -e ...
connect to yourdb
select versionnumber ...
EOF
```

See also [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787459/db2-query-in-shell-script-doesnt-run-with-empty-results-in-shell).

Answer (score 0):

There two other methods to obtain the version number:

- `db2pd -v`
- `db2level` - see here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/c0020806.html

I would suggest using that because they are lighter on resources.

Comment: I am trying to read just the base version into a variable for use later in the script. db2level and db2pd -v are returning less structured output. It could be possible with db2ls and awk but would like to avoid this as there can be multiple versions installed on same server. The query against sysversions is done with specific authid to avoid this.